# EMR ec2 cluster terraform creation fails due to iinsufficient EC2 permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-emr

trying to build an ec2 emr cluster but getting an iam error. I ran a gui build into a throw away account with auto scaling set up and no other config, then copied the defaultroles it used with my terraform module.

The error is

```
 Error: waiting for EMR Cluster (j-2MNN6IBMMKLVS) to create: unexpected state 'TERMINATED_WITH_ERRORS', wanted target 'RUNNING, WAITING'. last error: VALIDATION_ERROR: Service role arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/dev-emr-role has insufficient EC2 permissions. EC2 Message: AmazonEC2Exception: You are not authorized to perform this operation. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 403; Error Code: UnauthorizedOperation; Request ID: 97455539-4d1e-4bc7-bbf5-8a0520e0d55d; Proxy: null)
│ 
│   with aws_emr_cluster.cluster,
│   on emr.tf line 1, in resource "aws_emr_cluster" "cluster":
│    1: resource "aws_emr_cluster" "cluster" {
│
```

The role which it errors on is below:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_emr_service_role" {
  name = "${local.full_name}-role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = [
            "elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com",
            "application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "emr-service-role" {
  name        = "${local.full_name}-policy"
  description = "copy of EMR_DefaultRole policy"
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Resource" : "*",
        "Action" : [
          "ec2:*",
          "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
          "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
          "ec2:CancelSpotInstanceRequests",
          "ec2:CreateFleet",
          "ec2:CreateLaunchTemplate",
          "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
          "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
          "ec2:CreateTags",
          "ec2:DeleteLaunchTemplate",
          "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
          "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
          "ec2:DeleteTags",
          "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
          "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
          "ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions",
          "ec2:DescribeImages",
          "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
          "ec2:DescribeInstances",
          "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
          "ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplates",
          "ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls",
          "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
          "ec2:DescribePrefixLists",
          "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
          "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
          "ec2:DescribeSpotInstanceRequests",
          "ec2:DescribeSpotPriceHistory",
          "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
          "ec2:DescribeTags",
          "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
          "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints",
          "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServices",
          "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
          "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
          "ec2:ModifyImageAttribute",
          "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute",
          "ec2:RequestSpotInstances",
          "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
          "ec2:RunInstances",
          "ec2:TerminateInstances",
          "ec2:DeleteVolume",
          "ec2:DescribeVolumeStatus",
          "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
          "ec2:DetachVolume",
          "iam:GetRole",
          "iam:GetRolePolicy",
          "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
          "iam:ListRolePolicies",
          "iam:PassRole",
          "s3:CreateBucket",
          "s3:Get*",
          "s3:List*",
          "sdb:BatchPutAttributes",
          "sdb:Select",
          "sqs:CreateQueue",
          "sqs:Delete*",
          "sqs:GetQueue*",
          "sqs:PurgeQueue",
          "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
          "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
          "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
          "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms",
          "application-autoscaling:RegisterScalableTarget",
          "application-autoscaling:DeregisterScalableTarget",
          "application-autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
          "application-autoscaling:DeleteScalingPolicy",
          "application-autoscaling:Describe*"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
        "Resource" : "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/spot.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForEC2Spot*",
        "Condition" : {
          "StringLike" : {
            "iam:AWSServiceName" : "spot.amazonaws.com"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

i added the `ec2:*` at the top of the permissions to test that, but no joy, any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: What’s the rendered name of the role and did you attach the policy to it somewhere else? Safe to assume you interpolate the policy name in the ecr resource, to setup the dependency tree? Export TF_LOG=DEBUG in your shell and share the output of the ecr and policy creation.

Comment: Thats it! didnt actually attach the policy!